# Enable armv6 FFmpeg crashed under Android NDK

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk, armv6

I compile the FFmpeg under the armv5, it can work well on Android NDK r5, but I compile the FFmpeg under the armv6, it can success, but when I call the function av_new_stream, it is crashed, and it is crashed on the libavutil.c/rational.c:

```
if(num<=max && den<=max){
    a1= (AVRational){num, den};
    den=0;
}
```

Dose anyone encounter this problem?

```
The LOCAL_FLAGS
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_ARM_MODE := arm
LOCAL_MODULE    := ffmpeg
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DHAVE_AV_CONFIG_H  -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -DPIC  -std=gnu99 -march=armv6
```

Is there something error here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running your code under the emulator, this is perfectly normal. The emulator only supports ARMv5. Not ARMv6 and certainly not ARMv7.

**Update:** This is not true anymore with the newer versions of the emulator. It fully supports ARMv7.